# Incomplete type error when using overloaded constructor

Tags: c++

I've added a C++ class to help with simulations I'm running. It was working fine, until I added another constructor with different inititation parameters, after which the compiler complains about an 'incomplete type' error with the original constructor that was working before. CLion also complains it can't find a matching constructor, even though its the same one I've been using until now.

PS. I'm creating 2 separate instances of the class (1 in main, 1 in another class also initialised in main)...not sure if this is maybe an issue?

Here's the code:

#### SimEnv.hpp

```
#ifndef SIMENV
#define SIMENV
#include "ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp"

class SimEnv
{
private:
    int p1, p2;
public:
    SimEnv(ClassContainingParams);    // This is the bad constructor
    SimEnv(int, int);
};
#endif
```

#### SimEnv.cpp

```
#include "SimEnv.hpp"

/* This is the bad constructor */
SimEnv::SimEnv(ClassContainingSomeParams p) : 
    p1(p.getP1()), p2(p.getP2())
{}

SimEnv(SimEnv(int p1, int p2) : p1(p1), p2(p2)
{}
```

#### ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp

```
#ifndef CLASSCONTAININGSOMEPARAMS
#define CLASSCONTAININGSOMEPARAMS
#include "SimEnv.hpp"

ClassContainingSomeParams
{
    public:
        ClassContainingSomeParams();
        void runSim();
        int getP1();
        int getP2();
    private:
        int p1, p2;
};

#endif
```

#### ClassContainingSomeParams.cpp

```
#include "ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp"

ClassContainingSomeParams::ClassContainingSomeParams() : p1(0), p2(0)
{}

void ClassContainingSomeParams::runSim()
{          
    SimEnv env(p1, p2);
    // Do some stuff
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp"
#include "SimEnv.hpp"

int main()
{
    ClassContainingSomeParams p;
    SimEnv env(p);
    // Do some stuff
    return 0;
}
```

The exact errors I'm getting are

`SimEnv.hpp:10:33: error: field 'ClassContainingParams' has incomplete type 'SimEnv'`

`ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp:5:1: error: 'ClassContainingSomeParams' does not name a type`

Do I need to place the class declaration and initialisation into the header file? If so, why?

Comment: What is `ClassContainingParams`? You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: If you think the contents of header `ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp` are relevant to your question, you're right. It therefore escapes me why relevant content (such as the definition of `ClassContainingParams` supposedly within said header) was omitted from your question. To the soothsaying: My crystal ball tells me you reused the same header include guard fence post macros in both header files (`ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp` and `SimEnv.hpp`), because copy/paste is a cruel wench.

Comment: @WhozCraig Valid point, but I checked and each header has a unique include guard. I'll update the question with the `ClassContainingSomeParams.cpp/hpp` code

Comment: @Jabberwocky edited in the implementation

Comment: @Yassie there's a circular inclusion right there

Comment: @Moia but to create the object in the ClassContainingSomeParams class, I need to have that inclusion, right? Or are there ways around that

Comment: @Yassie as I said in previous answer, use forward declaration to avoid it. Anyway this smell as bad design

Comment: Any chance you could post that answer again?

Comment: @Yassie I'm doing it

Comment: Please read the page on creating a [mcve]. Things like `getP1` and `namespace Namespace` are *not* part of your problem, and you should eliminate them as part of the debugging you should be doing on your way to posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a circular inclusion between `ClassContainingParams.hpp` and `SimEnv.hpp`.

change your `ClassContainingParams` to `ClassContainingParams*` or `const ClassContainingParams&` and move the inclusion of `ClassContainingParams.hpp` in `SimEnv.cpp`.

```
#ifndef SIMENV
#define SIMENV

class ClassContainingSomeParams;

namespace Namespace
{
    class SimEnv
    {
    private:
        size_t p1, p2;
        size_t* pTracker;
        void init();
    public:
        SimEnv(const ClassContainingParams&);
        SimEnv(size_t, size_t);
        size_t func1();
        size_t func2();
    };
}
#endif
```

SimEnv.cpp

```
#include <SimEnv.hpp>
#include <ClassContainingSomeParams.hpp>

namespace Namespace
{
    SimEnv::SimEnv(const ClassContainingSomeParams& p) : 
        p1(p.getP1()), p2(p.getP2())
    {
        init();
    }

    SimEnv(SimEnv(size_t p1, size_t p2) : p1(p1), p2(p2)
    {
        init();
    }

    void SimEnv::init()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm initialised" << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I did include the `ClassContainingParams.hpp` in the original. I've updated the question. Sorry for missing that

Comment: @Yassie `ClassContainingSomeParams` belong to some other namespace?

Comment: As stated in other comments, the content of `ClassContainingSomeParams .hpp` is relevant

Comment: No, same namespace. I've tried adding the namespace before the class name (i.e. `SimEnv(Namespace::ClassContainingParams);`), but the compiler then complains about invalid usage of '::'. I'll update the question as well

Comment: @Yassie please do provide an implementation of `ClassContainingParams`